# SQL Server : master/slave table one to many relation EF code-first

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, master-slave

I want to know what is the right way to create and reference the following situation.

I have the following SQL Server tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Mail] [nvarchar](150) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_MasterSlave]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MasterID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SlaveID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NULL
)
```

A user can be the master of multiple other users, so it´s an one-to-many relationship.

When trying to create the constraints,

```sql
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserMasterSlaves] 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),

CONSTRAINT [FK_UserMasterSlaves_User_MasterID] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([MasterID]) REFERENCES [User] ([ID]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_UserMasterSlaves_User_SlaveID] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([SlaveID]) REFERENCES [User] ([ID]) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint FK_UserMasterSlaves_User_SlaveID on table User_MasterSlave may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What is the right way to do it?

Kind regards

-- EDIT --

Implementing a trigger to check for the second constraint is an option when touching the database. Is there a solution for EF code-first, without touching the database manually and without 3rd-party libraries?

Comment: *"I get an error that thats not possible"* `thats not possible` isn't a SQL Server error. What is the *actual* error you are getting?

Comment: Added the error message to the question

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. If you want the other foreign key to cascade, you'll need to implement a trigger.

Comment: By looking at the error it can be concluded that if you specify on delete cascade than it is possible to make a super entry which upon deletion may delete all the other rows from the table. That is why it is throwing error maybe